# Read csv in chunks with polars efficiently (with limited available RAM)

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

I'm trying to read a big CSV (6.4 Go approx.) on a small machine (small laptop on windows with 8Go of RAM) before storing it into a SQLite database (I'm aware there are alternatives, that's not the point here).

*In case it's needed the file I'm using can be found on [that page](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/base-sirene-des-entreprises-et-de-leurs-etablissements-siren-siret/); in the tab "Fichiers", it should be labelled "Sirene : Fichier StockEtablissementHistorique [...]". This file is today around 37 millions lines long.*

Being a big fan of pandas and I've nonetheless decided to try polars which is much advertised those days.

The inferred dataframe should also be joined to another produced with `pl.read_database` (which produces a pl.DataFrame and no pl.LazyFrame).

- My first try involved a LazyFrame and (naive) hope that `scan_csv` with `low_memory` argument would suffice to handle the RAM consumption. It completly freezed my computer after overconsumption of RAM.
- I gave it another try using the `n_rows` along with `skip_rows_after_header`. But if the
  `pl.read_csv(my_path, n_rows=1_000_000)` works fine, `pl.read_csv(my_path, n_rows=1_000_000, skip_rows_after_header=30_000_000)` seems to take forever (a lot more than a simple loop to find the count of lines).
- I've also tried the `pl.read_csv_batched` but it seems also to take forever (maybe to compute those first statistics **not** described in the documentation).
- The only way I found to handle the file with polars completly is to handles slices from a LazyFrame and collect it. Something like this :

  ```
  df = (
      pl.scan_csv(
          url,
          separator=",",
          encoding="utf8",
          infer_schema_length=0,
          low_memory=True,
      )
      .lazy()
      .select(pl.col(my_cols)
      # do some more processing, for instance 
      .filter(pl.col("codePaysEtrangerEtablissement").is_null())
  )
  chunksize=1_000_000
  for k in range(max_iterations:)
      chunk = df.slice(chunksize*k, chunksize).collect()
      chunk = chunk.join(my_other_dataframe, ... )
      # Do some more things like storing the chunk in a database.
  ```

  This "solution" seems to handle the memory but performs very slowly.

I've found another solution which seems to work nicely (which I'll post as provisional answer) but makes use of pandas read_csv with chunksize.
This is as good as is goes and works only because (thankfully) there is no groupby involved in my process.

I'm pretty sure there should be an easier "pure polars" way to proceed.

---

**EDIT**

The other dataframe mentionned here (`my_other_dataframe` in the code sample) is small. It's a dataframe of around 36k lines which is strictly used to convert the field "codeCommuneEtablissement" from it's 5-long string to a primary key of integers which is stored in another table. I kept it mentionned in the sample here to explain why you needed to collect the dataframe earlier, as you can't join a LazyFrame and a DataFrame.

Comment: You can call `.lazy()` on a DataFrame to get a LazyFrame and then use it within your join.

Comment: You can't join a lazyframe and dataframe but it's trivial to make a dataframe lazy by just doing `df.lazy()` then you have two lazyframes that can be joined.

Comment: I can't replicate the `pl.read_csv_batched` behaviour - it returns instantly for me. Perhaps you can share a code example for how you used it?

Comment: @jqurious read_csv_batched returns instantly. But next_batches() doesn't, do you confirm?

Comment: `next_batches()` also returns instantly. From a quick test, `.next_batches(6)` seemed to be the optimal size on my system. I'm guessing you may have used `.next_batches(chunksize)` i.e. `1_000_000`? `.read_csv_batched(batch_size=)` controls the number of rows per batch. `.next_batches(N)` says you want `N` batches at a time. so passing `chunksize` to `.next_batches()` is "wrong" if that is what is going on.

Comment: @jqurious No I passed `next_batches(1)` (I also tested fiddling with `n_threads` and `batch_size`). I suspect this might be due to those "mysterious" statistics which are not detailed in the documentation yet (and are also not easily available from the source as those seem to be in the rust part).

Comment: Ah, I see. Strange.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to answer this question as I don't know what your other df looks like and I don't know exactly what you're doing that crashes your computer but here are a few observations/suggestions.

arrow and, by extension, polars isn't optimized for strings so one of the worst things you could do is load a giant file with all the columns being loaded as strings.

From the [`scan_csv`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_csv.html) docs

> **infer_schema_length**
> Maximum number of lines to read to infer schema. If set to 0, all columns will be read as pl.Utf8.

You are setting that to 0 which means you're loading a giant file as all strings. Don't don't do that. Either set it to something reasonable or manually set the `dtypes` parameter. Ideally, the latter. Additionally, if there are columns that are strings but have relatively few unique values then you can make them categoricals to save more memory. Also, settings your integers to the smallest variation will also save some memory. One issue with Categoricals is that it's trickier to join on those columns. To get around that try:

```
import polars as pl
with pl.StringCache():
    dtypes={
    'siren':pl.UInt32(),
    'nic':pl.UInt32(),
    'siret':pl.UInt64(),
    'dateFin':pl.Date(),
    'dateDebut':pl.Date(),
    'etatAdministratifEtablissement':pl.Categorical(),
    'changementEtatAdministratifEtablissement':pl.Boolean(),
    'enseigne1Etablissement':pl.Categorical(),
    'enseigne2Etablissement':pl.Categorical(),
    'enseigne3Etablissement':pl.Categorical(),
    'changementEnseigneEtablissement':pl.Boolean(),
    'denominationUsuelleEtablissement':pl.Categorical(),
    'changementDenominationUsuelleEtablissement':pl.Boolean(),
    'activitePrincipaleEtablissement':pl.Categorical(),
    'nomenclatureActivitePrincipaleEtablissement':pl.Categorical(),
    'changementActivitePrincipaleEtablissement':pl.Boolean(),
    'caractereEmployeurEtablissement':pl.Categorical(),
    'changementCaractereEmployeurEtablissement':pl.Boolean()
    }

    df=pl.scan_csv("StockEtablissementHistorique_utf8.csv", 
                dtypes=dtypes)
    other_df=pl.read_database(your_query, your_conn_str).with_columns(pl.col(string_cols_to_join_on).cast(pl.Categorical())).lazy()
```

As an aside, some quick stats...

From here if I do `df.collect().estimated_size('gb')` it comes back as 4.57.

In contrast if I do `pl.read_csv(thefile).estimated_size('gb')` then it's 10.5 so there are significant savings in changing the column types.

You might need to keep everything in that StringCache context until you collect, I'm not sure how the StringCache interacts with LazyFrames. Since it takes basically no time for me to run the scan_csv, it's clearly not establishing the Categorical indexing right away.

It might also behoove you to resave the csv as multiple parquets that you then lazily load as a dataset via pyarrow.

Comment: In fact, I did load the columns setting the dtypes but mostly kept up with str (for instance "siret" might seem like an integer but are notorious french primary keys designed as strings - I'm not 100% sure they can't start with a 0). Your explanations on dtypes are very welcomed (especially your reflexions on categoricals), but if I left it at that my algorithm is bound to fail sometime when the file increase (or with another heavier file). Do you think you could detail the way to resave/explode the csv efficiently (as I said, `skip_rows_after_header` doesn't seem efficient)?

Comment: I confirm siret are strings, many do start with zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Note that polars also has a `pl.read_csv_batched` which gives you an iterator over chunks.

Example from the docs:

```py
reader = pl.read_csv_batched(
    "./tpch/tables_scale_100/lineitem.tbl", separator="|", try_parse_dates=True
)  

batches = reader.next_batches(5)  

for df in batches:  
    print(df)
```

See docs page: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_csv_batched.html#polars.read_csv_batched

Other than that, follow the tips from Deans answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76392237/6717054

Comment: Hey Ritchie, an update on this - OP has tried `pl.read_csv_batched` but `.next_batches(1)` is not returning for them/taking a very long time - I cannot replicate this. Is there a way for them to debug this?

Comment: No, that sounds like a malformed csv leading to some issues in the batched csv reader. If he can reproduce, I'd love to get an issue on that to see if we can fix that.

It works on your side?

Comment: Yeah, works fine for me using the data they linked to: https://files.data.gouv.fr/insee-sirene/StockEtablissementHistorique_utf8.zip (The file is 985mb download / ~6.8GB unzipped)

Comment: Thanks for these contributions; I confirm I checked the state of the file during download (not through it's hashed value bug through it's length nonetheless). Reading it through pandas didn't trigger any exception altogether, though I don't think this is linked to any malformation of any form.

Answer (score 0):

This solution makes use of pandas' way to chunk CSV. I found Pandas' csv reader more mature than polars' ; it handles memory consumption very easily through it's TextFileReader object.

Note that this will work as long as there are no groupby involved.

```
 reader = (
      pd.read_csv(url, sep=",", encoding="utf8", iterator=True, usecols=my_cols, chunksize=1_000_000
      )
 for chunk in reader:
     df = (
         pl.DataFrame(chunk)
         .lazy()
         # do some more processing, for instance 
         .filter(pl.col("codePaysEtrangerEtablissement").is_null())
         .collect()
     )
     df = df.join(my_other_dataframe, ... )
     # Do some more things like storing the chunk in a database.
```

Comment: you say this uses Pandas's csv reader but your reader definition has pl.read_csv. Is that  a typo and it should be pd?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that